# How is it possible to create wires/circuits that are nanometer in size?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microprocessor, pcb-fabrication

[image]

This image from wikipedia shows -

> An array of 17 purpose-built oxygen-depleted titanium dioxide
>   memristors built at HP Labs, imaged by an atomic force microscope. The
>   wires are about 50 nm, or 150 atoms, wide.

How would you explain to a layman how this is done? If I want to drill a fine hole I need a  finer drill. What tools are used to create these 150 atom wide wires? How are these tools created?

If some sort of chemical process is used how is it directed/controlled to achieve such precision? I imagine atoms would run everywhere in a test tube and it won't be easy to take a set of copper atoms and put them in a line. 
And then you need to ensure that these wires do not touch each other.

How does one create such circuits?

Comment: I'm sure someone will describe the process way much better than I ever can, but I know a company down the road from my home ( http://asml.nl/ ) that makes wafersteppers which are used for making these immensely tiny structures:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper

Comment: Slightly off topic when it gets even crazier with MicroelEctroMechanical Systems (MEMS). Couple orders of magnitude larger than the 50nm scale you refer to, but these are actual working mechanics at micrometer scale! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems and http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/semitech_en/kap_7/illustr/gear_small.gif

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photolithography

It's basically a photographic etching process. In the extreme case, you *can* move individual atoms around with what is effectively a very fine needle and a precise electric charge, but that's not practical for anything other than experimentation.